# delete listview item with delete button

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, adapter

```
       In below code you swipe listview item by your hand but i want when i click on list view item item automatically swipe left to right and display delete button on screen.
private ListView list;
    private MyAdapter m_Adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        SwipeListView l = null;
        try {
            l = new SwipeListView(this);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        l.exec();
        m_Adapter = new MyAdapter();
        for (int i = 1; i < 30; i++) {
            //
            m_Adapter.addItem("Item " + i);
        }
        //
        list.setAdapter(m_Adapter);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public ListView getListView() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return list;
    }

    @Override
    public void onSwipeItem(boolean isRight, int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        m_Adapter.onSwipeItem(isRight, position);
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClickListener(ListAdapter adapter, int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    //
    public class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

        protected List<String> m_List;
        private final int INVALID = -1;
        protected int DELETE_POS = -1;

        public MyAdapter() {
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
            m_List = new ArrayList<String>();
        }

        public void addItem(String item) {
            //
            m_List.add(item);
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        public void addItemAll(List<String> item) {
            //
            m_List.addAll(item);
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        public void onSwipeItem(boolean isRight, int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (isRight == false) {
                DELETE_POS = position;
            } else if (DELETE_POS == position) {
                DELETE_POS = INVALID;
            }
            //
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        public void deleteItem(int pos) {
            //
            m_List.remove(pos);
            DELETE_POS = INVALID;
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return m_List.size();
        }

        @Override
        public String getItem(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return m_List.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(final int position, View convertView,
                ViewGroup parent) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (convertView == null) {
                convertView = LayoutInflater.from(MainActivity.this).inflate(
                        R.layout.item, null);
            }
            TextView text = ViewHolderPattern.get(convertView, R.id.text);
            TextView text1 = ViewHolderPattern.get(convertView, R.id.text1);
            RatingBar ratingBar = (RatingBar) findViewById(R.id.ratingbar);

            Button delete = ViewHolderPattern.get(convertView, R.id.delete);
            if (DELETE_POS == position) {
                delete.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            } else
                delete.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            delete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    deleteItem(position);
                }
            });

            text.setText("ssss");
            text1.setText("ssss");
            //ratingBar.setRating(5);

            return convertView;
        }
    }

    public static class ViewHolderPattern {
        // I added a generic return type to reduce the casting noise in client
        // code
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        public static <T extends View> T get(View view, int id) {
            SparseArray<View> viewHolder = (SparseArray<View>) view.getTag();
            if (viewHolder == null) {
                viewHolder = new SparseArray<View>();
                view.setTag(viewHolder);
            }
            View childView = viewHolder.get(id);
            if (childView == null) {
                childView = view.findViewById(id);
                viewHolder.put(id, childView);
            }
            return (T) childView;
        }
    }
```

one extra swipelistview.java file is there.I want when you click on listview item listview item swipe left to right and when click on delete button full listview item delete from listview.I swipe listview properly by hand but i want clickable moment on listview item in android.click then swipe listview item and show delete button

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you want to change the standard behaviour of the Eco System, Swipe Action is usually performed when user swipes on the Screen. Doing a swipe Action on click or touch is rather annoying. Think about it.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this library **[SwipeListview](https://github.com/47deg/android-swipelistview)**

Hope It is your requirment..